# Sending Multipart image using Volley and receive in PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, android-volley

I have a webservice in PHP and I'm using Volley to send informations this webservice. Now, I need send a multipart image and params using volley I can do that but I don't know how I can receive the informations in PHP.

My webservice was made using CakePHP and I'm trying use `$this->request->data` to receive informations but doesn't works. Tried `$this->request->params` also and it doesn't works.

The problem is, the file and params are not received in CakePHP and I don't know how I could do this.

How could I do this ?

Trying

**Volley Multipart**

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
    private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    private final Response.Listener mListener;
    private final File mImageFile;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private Map<String, String> params;
    private String mFieldUpload;

    public MultipartRequest(String url,
                                 Map<String, String> params,
                                 Response.Listener listener,
                                 Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
                                 File imageFile,
                                 String fieldUpload){
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;
        mImageFile = imageFile;
        mFieldUpload = fieldUpload;
        this.params = params;

        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String cred = String.format("%s:%s", BasicAuthenticationRest.USERNAME, BasicAuthenticationRest.PASSWORD);
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(cred.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        headers.put("Authorization", auth);

        return headers;
    }


    private void buildMultipartEntity(){
        mBuilder.addBinaryBody(mFieldUpload, mImageFile, ContentType.create("image/jpg"), mImageFile.getName());
        mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        try {
            if(!params.isEmpty()){
                for (String key: params.keySet()){
                    mBuilder.addTextBody(key, params.get(key));
                    Log.i("PARAMS->", key + " - " + params.get(key));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType(){
        return mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try{
            mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
        }catch (IOException e){
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream bos, building the multipart request.");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response){
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response){
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

**Sending image**

```
public MultipartRequest addUserApp(User user, File file, final UserAdapter listener){
        urlPost.append(WebServiceURL.getBaseWebServiceURL() + "Users/addUserApp.json");           


        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("nome", user.getNome());
        params.put("email", user.getEmail());
        params.put("senha", user.getSenha());
        params.put("image", file != null ? file.getName() : "");
        params.put("role", String.valueOf(user.getRole()));
        params.put("status", String.valueOf(user.getStatus()));
        params.put("tipoLogin", user.getTipoLogin());

        MultipartRequest mr = new MultipartRequest(urlPost.toString(),
                params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        Log.i(TAG, jsonObject.toString());

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                        Log.e("VolleyError", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                },
                file,
                "form"){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return getHeadersJson();
            }

        };
        return mr;
    }
```

**CakePHP to receive informations**

```
public function addUserApp(){
            $this->autoRender = false;
            //$results = $this->request->params;
            $results = $this->request->data;

            return json_encode($results);

        }
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I edited `The file and params are not received in CakePHP and I don't know how I could do this.`

Comment: Did you check `addUserApp()` gets called? Maybe you are using wrong url.